# Tensor distributes over direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, direct-sum

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $(M_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of $A$-modules (for some index set $I$). I am trying to show that for all $A$-modules $N$,

$N \otimes (\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i) \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I}(N \otimes M_i)$,

i.e. the tensor product distributes over the direct sum. So far I have shown that the map $f : N \times (\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i) \to \bigoplus_{i\in I}(N \otimes M_i)$ given by $f(n, (m_i)_{i\in I}) = (n \otimes m_i)_{i\in I}$ is $A$-bilinear, and hence by the universal property of the tensor product, we induce a module homomorphism $\hat{f} : N \otimes (\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i) \to \bigoplus_{i\in I}(N \otimes M_i)$ which furthermore satisfies $\hat{f}(n \otimes (m_i)_{i \in I}) = (n \otimes m_i)_{i\in I}$ for all $n \in N$ and all $(m_i) \in \bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i$.

It seems intuitive that $\hat{f}$ is the desired isomorphism, but I can't seem to argue the bijectivity. I'm not used to using tensor products, but I know that that the elements of the tensor product aren't all simply of the form $n \otimes (m_i)_{i \in I}$, so even injectivity is difficult for me to see. How can I show $\hat{f}$ is bijective?

Comment: It is eaasier to define an inverse

Comment: What would that look like? Obviously you should send $(n \otimes m_i)_{i \in I}$ to $n \otimes (m_i)_{i \in I}$, but how do I know that extends to a well-defined map?

Comment: Use universal properties of direct sum and tensor product to define a natural map, which agrees with what you have written